# convert Timezone to mysql date format Y-m-d

Tags: php, date, timezone

I have a timezone date that have been posted to some PHP script.
like (Tue Dec 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time).

Now all what i need is simply convert that date to match mysql date which in "Y-m-d" format.

Is there any direct function? How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) will handle this easily.

```
$dt = new DateTime('Tue Dec 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Thanks John That works very fine and lovely :) But how can i take that (Egypt Standard Time) off, to reach same format you introduce?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for. Can you try to explain in more detail?

Comment: if you got my variable above it contains (Egypt Standard Time) at its end. Your code is working very fine, however JavaScript send me      (Tue Dec 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time). Which is not working when yours are working without that end (Egypt Standard Time). my question is how to take that (Egypt Standard Time) out to match your syntax? :)

Comment: Use `str_replace('(Egypt Standard Time)', '', 'Tue Dec 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time)')`

Comment: Wonderful, that working very well I came over my pain now, thanks JOOOOHHHHNNNN :)

Comment: one more is to use date.toUTCString() to post it without that () !!